# Is all ReLu doing changing all negative values to 0?

Tags: neural-network, conv-neural-network, relu

I have just spent an hour reading a paper on Rectified Linear Units (ReLu). I find it very difficult to unpack the maths involved.

Is it basically just saying that, after you do convulution and pooling, you change any negative values to 0?

Is that it ?

Answer (score 0):

You are almost right. However, for input values that are greater than zero, it becomes a usual linear function. Hence, the function is:

```
f(x) = 0, when x < 0;
     = x, otherwise

(or)

f(x) = max(0, x)
```